# GitLab CE - How to load a .net (core) build environment on the runner?

Tags: .net-core, gitlab-ci

I'm using GitLab CE as our source control system. It's on prem but updated to the latest version.

I have a Runner configured to build .net projects.

I have a dotNet Core Project that I want to build. The problem i'm having is loading the .net Build environments. I'm trying to run this to establish the environment:

```
`- 'cmd /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"'
```

This executes correct to the point that I get this output:

```
$ cmd /K "C:\Program Files ^(x86^)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 MSBuild Command Prompt
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\352e1762\0\online\WebApp>$ nuget restore src/Online-WebApp.sln
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.5.179.9764' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.
...rest removed...
```

The problem is when it gets the job step in the Yml, the `msbuild` command is reported as not recognized.

Here's the full YAML.

Note that manually setting the `PATH` worked to find `msbuild`....

```
variables:
  DATABASE_URL: "example=not-real" #just to show this is an option; https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html

stages:
  - build

before_script:
 #- 'PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin'
 #- 'cmd /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"'
 #- 'cmd /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\LaunchDevCmd.bat"'
 - 'cmd /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"'
 - 'nuget restore src/Online-WebApp.sln'

# What is important, is that each job is run independently from each other. "build" is a job.
build:
 stage: build
 script:
  - 'msbuild src/Online-WebApp.sln /t:Clean,ReBuild /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU"'
  - 'dotnet pack src/Online-WebApp/Online-WebApp.csproj -c Release -v d --output nupkgs --no-build'
 only:
  - master
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `before_script` section, don't use `cmd /k`, use `call` instead.

For example:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"
```